# How to select values from a list of differently named attributes?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given an XPath query that results in a list of differently-named attributes, is there something you can append to that query to select just the values and omit the attribute names, etc? (For portability, I'm aiming for XPath 1.0)

Example XML of people with addresses:

```
<people>
  <person workaddr="foo" homeaddr="bar"/>
  <person workaddr="baz" homeaddr="foo"/>
  <person workaddr="qux" homeaddr="zoo"/>
</people>
```

My XPath query for finding all the addresses of any person associated in any way with address `foo`:

```
//person[@*='foo']/@*['addr' = substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('addr') +1) and . != '']
```

(I realize that this would match any person with *any* attribute whose value is `foo`, not just `foo` *addresses*, since in the real case there are other attributes besides work and home addresses. If you happen to know how to improve my query to limit the attribute value checking to attributes whose names end in `addr` that would be a great bonus)

The result of my query at least according to http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output is:

```
Attribute='homeaddr=bar'
Attribute='workaddr=foo'
Attribute='homeaddr=foo'
Attribute='workaddr=baz'
```

What I'd like is just the values: `bar foo foo baz` or even `bar foo baz`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to add `string()` to get just values: `//person[@*='foo']/@*['addr' = substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('addr') +1) and . != '']/string()`

Comment: `string()` is a function, not a node test. So calling `string()` in path step won't work in XPath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way that particular XPath tester persents attribute in the output. You can easily switch to different tools which serves your needs better, for example, http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath doesn't print attribute name in the output as you can see [in this demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8d65585b8d8e29fde5f63428e420d413). Also XPath processor libraries, if you're using one, always provide a way to read just the value of an attribute in its API.

Now regarding the other problem, you seem to have limited the result to attributes which name ends with 'addr', so just implement the same predicate on the previous path step to limit the check for 'foo' to attributes which name ends with 'addr' :

```
//person[@*[
    'addr' = substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('addr') +1) 
    and .='foo'
]]
 /@*[
    'addr' = substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('addr') +1) 
    and . != ''
 ]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/25b70da1c389700bf1820afba48c2a76)</kbd>**